# How can i create with fastest method 250.000.000.000 rows data

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb

Helllo all,

I wanted to create on azure cosmosdb items which one has location coordinates.
Yesterday i created a method on API below:

```
  [HttpGet("createzone")]

    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> CreateZones()

    {
        Container container = database.GetContainer(containerId);

        double x = 38.988599999993035;
        double y = 26.003399999999992;
        int id = 524962;
        while (y < 45.0000000001)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
            Zone newZone = new Zone
            {
                Id = "Zone." + id.ToString(),
                Title = "Zone" + id.ToString(),
                Owner = null,
                Coordinate = new Coordinate { Latitude = x, Longitude = y },
                PartitionKey = "id." + id.ToString()

            };
            await container.CreateItemAsync<Zone>(newZone, new PartitionKey(newZone.PartitionKey));

            x += 0.0002;
            id += 1;
            if (x>42)
            {
                y += 0.0002;
                x = 36;
            }
        }
        return "done";
    }
```

according to my calculations it will take more than 3 years for the data to be generated if it continues like this

**What i neeed:**
Creating areas shown with squares on the map in the application and ensuring that all of these areas have a unique number. Like this:
[image]

I did same visual in my app now. but creating areas taking too much time.

How can i create on fastest way these items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like you have implemented this using [bulk import pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/tutorial-sql-api-dotnet-bulk-import) with Cosmos DB. There's a lot to gain using that. While doing this, also monitor the used RUs when you execute and consider increasing RUs for the duration of the operation.